# Encountered the symbol?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F5
  (tstg IN stage.numerostage%type) 
     return  sys-ryfcursor
DECLARE
BEGIN
    OPEN list for 
      SELECT count(*) as nbrmodule,sess.* 
     from session sess natural join enseigne  
     where numerostage=tstg;  
    RETURN list;        
END;
```

I get this error:

> encountered the symbol

Comment: Your error message would probably be improved if you posted the complete version of it.

Comment: And the db is? Pick one.

Comment: @user_0 what  u mean ?

Comment: @thuglife, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple **errors** in your **function**.

> sys-ryfcursor

It's `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

> DECLARE

You don't need the `DECLARE` keyword. Remove it.

A suggestion, always **compile** your code and use **SHOW ERRORS** in **SQL*Plus** or a similar client to see the **full error stack**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION F5(
  3        tstg   IN stage.numerostage%type)
  4      RETURN SYS-ryfcursor
  5      DECLARE
  6      BEGIN
  7        OPEN list FOR SELECT COUNT(*)
  8      AS
  9        nbrmodule,sess.* FROM session sess NATURAL JOIN enseigne WHERE numerostage=tstg;
 10        RETURN list;
 11      END;
 12      /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for FUNCTION F5:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/15     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "-" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character
         deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate
         result_cache accessible

SQL>
```

Comment: @thuglife Then edit your question and copy paste your session just like I have shown you.